# What is the command line to run arangodb (arangod.exe) 1.2.0 on windows?

Tags: arangodb

It demands `--server.endpoint` option, but nothing I give it works. Has anyone ever run this database on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done the following: Downloaded and installed "arango64.msi" into a directory "c:\Users\fceller\ArangoDB" under Windows 8. Switched into this directory and executed "shellExample.bat". This starts the server and you can access it via the browser under "localhost:8529".

As for the server.endpoint option: It either supports tcp or unix domain sockets (presumably not under Windows). For TCP the syntax is

tcp://127.0.0.1:8529